# mongodb mms monitoring agent does not find group members

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I have installed the latest mongodb mms agent (6.5.0.456) on ubuntu 16.04 and initialised the replicaset. Hence I am running a single node replicaset with the monitoring agent enabled. The agent works fine, however it does not seem to actually find the replicaset member:

```
[2018/05/26 18:30:30.222] [agent.info] [components/agent.go:Iterate:170] Received new configuration: Primary agent, Assigned 0 out of 0 plus 0 chunk monitor(s)
[2018/05/26 18:30:30.222] [agent.info] [components/agent.go:Iterate:182] Nothing to do. Either the server detected the possibility of another monitoring agent running, or no Hosts are configured on the Group.
[2018/05/26 18:30:30.222] [agent.info] [components/agent.go:Run:199] Done. Sleeping for 55s...
[2018/05/26 18:30:30.222] [discovery.monitor.info] [components/discovery.go:discover:746] Performing discovery with 0 hosts
[2018/05/26 18:30:30.222] [discovery.monitor.info] [components/discovery.go:discover:803] Received discovery responses from 0/0 requests after 891ns
```

I can see two processes for monitor agents:

```
/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent -conf /etc/mongodb-mms/monitoring-agent.config >> /var/log/mongodb-mms/monitoring-agent.log 2>&1
/usr/bin/mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent -conf /etc/mongodb-mms/monitoring-agent.config
```

However if I terminate one, it also tears down the other, so I do not think that is the problem.

So, question is what is the Group that the agent is referring to. Where is that configured? Or how do I find out which Group the agent refers to and how do I check if the group is configured correctly.

The rs.config() looks fine, with one replicaset member, which has a host field, which looks just fine. I can use that value to connect to the instance using the mongo command. no auth is configured.

**EDIT**

It kind of looks that the cloud manager now needs to be configured with the seed host. Then it starts to discover all the other nodes in the replicaset. This seems to be different to pre-cloud-manager days, where the agent was able to track the rs - if I remember correctly... Probably there still is a way to get this done easier, so I am leaving this question open for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, question is what is the Group that the agent is referring to. Where is that configured? Or how do I find out which Group the agent refers to and how do I check if the group is configured correctly.

Configuration values for the Cloud Manager agent (such as `mmsGroupId` and `mmsApiKey`) are set in the config file, which is `/etc/mongodb-mms/monitoring-agent.config` by default. The agent needs this information in order to communicate with the Cloud Manager servers.

For more details, see [Install or Update the Monitoring Agent](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/nav/install-monitoring-agent/) and [Monitoring Agent Configuration](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/reference/monitoring-agent/) in the Cloud Manager documentation.

> It kind of looks that the cloud manager now needs to be configured with the seed host. Then it starts to discover all the other nodes in the replicaset.

Unless a MongoDB process is already managed by Cloud Manager automation, I believe it has always been the case that you need to [add an existing MongoDB process to monitoring](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/add-existing-mongodb-processes/) to start the process of initial topology discovery. Once a deployment is monitored, any changes in deployment membership should automatically be discovered by the Cloud Manager agent.

Production employments should have authentication and access control enabled, so in addition to adding a seed hostname and port via the Cloud Manager UI you usually need to provide appropriate credentials.